# How to connect to an API running on localhost from a React Native App running on an iPhone

Tags: react-native, asp.net-core-webapi

fairly new to all this but I'm trying to get my React Native app to connect to a .NET Core API running on my localhost.  I want to test on an iPhone so to connect I am using the QR code that is generated when starting the React Native app using Expo Client

The URL I tried using to connect to the API is:

```
https://localhost:51787
```

I also tried using the local IP address from Ipconfig

```
http://192.168.1.69:51787
```

And from another post that suggested trying this for iPhones :

```
http://10.0.2.2:51787
```

This is how I'm using it :-

```
  const login = () => {

    fetch('https://localhost:51787/api/Login?username=' + username + '&password=' + password, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
    
        // Do stuff here

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
```

Unfortunately the URLs that I tried do not work and I get the error 'Network Request Failed'

I have enabled Cross-Origin Request.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, thanks

Comment: `localhost` would be on your iphone. You have to use the host's ipaddress which has to be reachable from your iphone. Furthermore i think, iOS doesn't allow unsecured connections, so you have to use `https://`. But for that to work you have to serve also a certificate which is trusted by your phone ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with the node package localtunnel.

[Localtunnel](https://theboroer.github.io/localtunnel-www/)

You install it global and start it up pointing to the port your api is running on.

```
lt --port 8080
```

Then you get an url to point to from the outside world.

```
your url is: https://salty-beans-sneeze-87-***-***-191.loca.lt
```

I used it to test webhook functions from other websites redirecting to my localhost.

Comment: Not ideally what I wanted as I was hoping for something that I could implement locally but this does work so in the absence of anything else I'll accept this